# Firefox addon could not be installed because it's not compatible with Firefox 33.0 on Android

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I just finished building my first addon for Firefox using the new Addon SDK.

I'm able to download and install the addon on my desktop Firefox 33.0 and it runs without a problem, however when I try to install the same addon on Firefox for Android 33.0 I get an error message: "... could not be installed because it is not compatible with Firefox 33.0"

Do I need to do anything special to allow my addon to run on Firefox for Android? The addon is generic and there's no reason why it shouldn't run on Android

**EDIT**: It seems like the problem was indeed that some APIs are not supported in Firefox for Android, the link provided by willma contains all the information required to release an addon for mobile.

Comment: If you provided more info, we could provide more concrete advice. For example: a list of modules you are using from the SDK, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely you're using a module that isn't compatible with mobile. See [the mobile module compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Mobile_development#Module_Compatibility) for more details.